# Make Github organization projects public

Tags: github

Github *recently* introduced the project feature.

When projects are at repo level, if the repo itself is public, then, the projects are accessible to anyone.

Projects at the organization level, however, are only visible to organization members.

For example,  https://github.com/Toolwatchapp has one project, but you can't see it without being logged into Github.

Is there a way to make organisation projects public ?

Thanks,
M.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## Update (2018-04-06)

It's now possible: https://blog.github.com/2018-03-28-improved-organization-project-permissions/#public-organization-projects. Yay !

## Official Response by Github

Petros (GitHub Staff)

Hi Mathieu,

Thanks for writing in!

> Is there a way to make organization projects public?

This is not possible currently. Thanks for the suggestion though! I have added it to our list for our team to consider.

Cheers,
Petros

Comment: That's too bad. Making these org-projects public could make them much more useful.

Comment: In my use-case, I'd like to create an organization-wide project for "up for grabs"  tickets, which will include issues from various components our organization is building. Outside contributors should be able to see those issues even though they are not members of the organization. This will allow attracting more contributors to our projects.